# In MapInfo Professional, how do I get rid of the Search symbol?

Tags: mapinfo

In MapInfo, after I have searched using CTRL+F, it overlays a star onto the search result. How do I get rid of the resulting star?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to Map>Clear Cosmetic Layer. This will delete all the objects in the cosmetic layer. 
If you want to delete only specific objects, set the Cosmetic Layer editable in the Layer Control, select the star with the Selection button and delete.

Answer (score 1):

Go into menus

Options/Preferences/Styles...

Choose **Default Find Style**

[image]